# Нет изменений на сайте

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть файлы с расширением aspx.cs и .cs

Сайт на старом Asp.net

При нажатии на "отчёт",перекидывает на отдельную страницу с созданным отчётом,который можно скачать в Excel с расширением .xls

Но вот когда я что то меняю и сохраняю в файлах для создания этого отчёта,например меняю текст столбца,то на сайте не бывает этих изменений.

Я также проверил другие файлы с aspx.cs и .cs,тоже самое.

Значит нужно как то по другому сохранять эти файлы или что?
Мне нужно предоставить что-нибудь?

Comment: ASP сайты компилируются в .dll, которые уже кто-то запускает. Качайте Visual Studio, открывайте через нее .csproj или .sln файл (если есть), далее ПКМ по имени проекта - Опубликовать, выбираете "Папка", настраиваете как надо, ну и публикуете, на выходе будет измененный сайт.

Comment: Всё зависит от способа публикации сайта. Если у вас в корневой директории есть файл PrecompiledApp.config то это значит что сайт прошёл предварительную сборку и весь код находится в сборках в папке bin

Comment: есть папка bin,но нет файла PrecompiledApp.config

Comment: @Nikolay есть видеоролик?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть видеоролик?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ подготавливайте свой сайт через публикацию, в этом случае можно настроить что бы все страницы компилировалиьс в сборки и при изменениях вам придется перевыкладывать весь сайт, за то не будет проблем с тем что вы что то меняется, а изменений нет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть ли другие способы,чтобы были изменения?

Comment: А что вы все меня-то пингуете я не пойму?) Нету других способов. Сайт, это DLL, которые надо собрать из исходников, как и любой другой проект, все, точка. Единственное, что вы можете там изменить, так это может CSS, некоторые странички (если старая версия), и другие "статичные" документы, все. Не ищите обходных путей, я уже вам сказал что делать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Есть видеоролик на ютубе или где нибудь ещё по которому я смогу сделать это?

Comment: Может и есть, не знаю. Вы спрашиваете базу языка C#, а именно то, как собирать проект. Открывайте любой мануал, любую справку (не обязательно по вебу), и изучайте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вообщем есть таблица в отчёте и в нём есть td - мне нужно добавить в нём текст